Keep CSS in the bundle and extract it into a separate file simultaneously with webpack
Your webpack is currently set up as follows:
const path = require('path')
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");



module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',


    entry: {
        main: './src/index.ts',
        button: './src/components/Button',
        input: './src/components/Input',
        logo: './src/components/Logo',
        print: './src/helpers/print',
    },
    output: {
        filename: (pathData) => {
            if (pathData.chunk.name === 'print') return `helpers/${pathData.chunk.name}/[name].js`
            return pathData.chunk.name === 'main' ? 'index.js' : `components/${pathData.chunk.name}/[name].js`;
        },
        libraryTarget: "umd",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        library: 'my-library-name',
        clean: true
    },

    optimization: {
        // minimize: true,
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg|gif)$/,
                type: "asset/resource",
                generator: {
                    filename: 'assets/images/[name].[ext]',
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ts|tsx)?$/,
                use: ['ts-loader'],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                oneOf: [
                    {
                        resource: /common-varibels/, // Проверяем, содержит ли путь common-styles.scss
                        use: [
                            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                            'css-loader',
                            'sass-loader'
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        use: [
                            'style-loader',
                            'css-loader',
                            'sass-loader'
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".json", ".ts", ".tsx"],
    },

    externals: {
        "react": {
            root: 'React',
            commonjs2: 'react',
            commonjs: 'react',
            amd: 'react'
        },
        "react-dom": {
            root: 'ReactDOM',
            commonjs2: 'react-dom',
            commonjs: 'react-dom',
            amd: 'react-dom'
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({analyzerPort: 8885}),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "styles/common.css",
        }),
    ]
}

With this configuration, a file named common-variables.css will be extracted from the bundle into a separate .css file. I want to understand if there's a way, using webpack, to simultaneously keep a specific file in the bundle for import purposes and extract it into a separate file.
I tried to do this in the hope that all .scss files would first be added to the bundle, and then the (common-variables.css) file would be additionally extracted into a separate .css file during the build.
 {   test: /\.scss$/,
      use: ['style-loader','css-loader','sass-loader']
 },

 {
     test: /custom-styles\.scss$/,
     use: [ MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,'css-loader','sass-loader']
 },

However, this doesn't work; in any case, the common-variables.css file will be extracted from the bundle.
My question is whether it's possible to somehow, through webpack configuration or any other means, simultaneously keep common-variables.css in the compiled bundle and generate a separate .css file for it?
Thank you in advance.
